# Priming people with self-image/social-image concerns

Tags: priming

I have a hypothesis that if you prime people with self-image or social-image concerns, they will behave less anti-socially and more prosocially. For example, they litter less, they discriminate less against racial minorities, etc.

Are there any such studies examining this? If not, how can I prime people with self-image or social-image concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis is true, priming can affect human behavior in many different ways. Specifically pro-social behavior can be encouraged by simply displaying an [image of a pair of eyes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1686213/).

> We examined the effect of an image of a pair of eyes on contributions
>   to an honesty box used to collect money for drinks in a university
>   coffee room. People paid nearly three times as much for their drinks
>   when eyes were displayed rather than a control image. This finding
>   provides the first evidence from a naturalistic setting of the
>   importance of cues of being watched, and hence reputational concerns,
>   on human cooperative behaviour.

Also in a similar [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3855385/) the following results are found.

> We also found that
>   images of watching eyes reduced littering, although contrary to
>   previous findings this was only when there were larger numbers of
>   people around. With regard to our central aim, we found no evidence
>   that litter on the ground interacted non-additively with images of
>   eyes to induce increased littering behaviour. Our data therefore
>   support the hypothesis that images of eyes induce more pro-social
>   behaviour, independent of local norms. This finding has positive
>   implications for the application of eye images in combating
>   anti-social behaviour.

Comment: I saw the first study being demonstrated on a TV documentary a while ago and found that interesting.  I wish I could remember what the documentary was called